# How to extract only day from Context["execution_date"] and DR.exuection_date using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

How to extract only day from Context["execution_date"] and DR.exuection_date using Airflow.

I want to extract only day from Context["execution_date"] and DR.exuection_date to compare if both day are same or not.

**For example :**

```
From Date 01-04-2022 i Want to extract only 04
```

Answer (score 0):

Context["execution_date"] is from type datetime.datetime.

you can get the month from it by :

```
d = Context["execution_date"]
d.month
```

In case you have as a string, you can also split by "-":

```
month = Context["execution_date"].split("-")[1]
```

Comment: what about DR.exuection_date ? DR.exuection_date and context["execution_date"] should be same type.

Comment: you mean DagRun right? so yes, <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: Yes DagRun but both should be same type. Because I want to compare month from both Context and DagRun